# Subgroups of free product

Tags: group-theory

Is it true that $A\ast A\ast A$ always embeds in $A\ast A$ for every group $A$? If not, what about the case when $A$ is torsion-free?

As a motivation for this question, in my recent work (see the draft [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14353)) I defined an $A$-free group to be a free product of copies of a fixed free nilpotent group $A$ of class $k$. The case when $A=\mathbb{Z}$ is the ordinary free group. It is shown then that a residually $A$-free group is fully residually $A$-free iff it has a transivity property like this: for any two nilpotent subgroups $K_1$ and $K_1$ with class at most $k$, if $K_1\cap K_2\neq 1$ then $\langle K_1, K_2\rangle$ is also nilpotent of class at most $k$.

Now, when all free products of the form $\ast^nA$ embed in each other, we can simplify the definition of (fully) residually $A$-free groups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The group $\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ does not embed in the group $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$. The reason is that the latter group has an infinite cyclic subgroup of index $2$, whereas the former contains a free subgroup of rank $2$, and no finite index subgroup of a rank $2$ free group is infinite cyclic.

However, if $G$ is any group of cardinality $\ge 3$ then it is true that $G*G*G$ embeds in $G*G$. To see why, first express the latter group as $G_1 * G_2$.

Now choose two nontrivial elements $a,b \in G_1$ (which exist because $G_1$ has cardinality $\ge 3$).

Finally check that the three subgroups $G_1$, $aG_2a^{-1}$, and $bG_2b^{-1}$ freely generate a subgroup of $G_1 * G_2$ isomorphic to $G*G*G$.